# get the result of SELECT 1 query in DataTable and get the value in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I've a query which checks for username and password in database. I have used as `SELECT 1` query and set it in DataTable. Now how can I retrieve the value from DataTable since it doesnot have column name in DataTable.

```
protected void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string strQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM login WHERE USERNAME = @USERNAME AND PASSWORD = @PASSWORD";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@USERNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user_login.Value.Trim();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PASSWORD", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user_pass.Value.Trim();

            DBConnection conn_ = new DBConnection();

            dt = conn_.SelectData(cmd);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
                // how can I get the value

            }     
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Validate the existence of a username and password or return the actual username and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting the number `1`, so why you want to read it? You know if the entered password for the user was valid by checking `if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)`.

If you want to read the 1(for whatever reason) you can use the position of the column:

```
DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
int number1 = row.Field<int>(0); // first column
```